# Ajax form broken by client_side_validations gem?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm trying to make a comment system in Rails 3.1. The idea is to have the basic form be validated by the [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/) gem, and on success use Ajax to add it dynamically. Before I added the gem, everything was working (with the exception of error handling). After adding the gem, the page reloads on form submit. The client_side_validations gem appears to error out, which might be causing this -- I'm not sure how/why though. The Javascript error I get is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'validators[this[0].name]')
```

My form code:

```
= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], :remote => true, :validate => true) do |f|
  #comment-left
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :website
  #comment-right
    = f.input :content, :as => :text
    = f.button :submit
```

The Controller code:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

The Create.js.erb code:

```
$('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => @comment) %>').hide().insertBefore('#new_comment').slideDown();
```

And finally, the partial code:

```
.comment
  = image_tag(comment.gravatar_url)
  %span
    Posted by
    - unless comment.website.blank?
      = link_to comment.name, comment.website
    - else
      = comment.name
    on
    = comment.created_at.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
  %p= comment.content
```

I think that's everything relevant -- if you need the model code, just say so and I'll provide it. No custom validators are used though. Any insights as to why client_side_validations isn't working would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: any progress since november? I seem to be having this issue too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750174/client-side-validations-3-1-0-not-working-when-new-form-is-added-to-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this question and try it out,

[client_side_validations (3.1.0) not working when new form is added to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750174/client-side-validations-3-1-0-not-working-when-new-form-is-added-to-the-dom)

If its not solved,
 tell me.