# on layout:false losing client_side_validation properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am rendering partial on click using jquery. Here is the code for it

```
$('.actCell').click(function (){
    alert('Load was performed.');
    $.get('/policies/new', function(data) {
        $('.policyAddForm').html(data);

    });
});
```

Here is the controller code

```
 def new
    @policy = Policy.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @policy }
    end
 end
```

This is my application.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Passport</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

</head>
<body>


<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/assets/ph_logo.png">
    <div class="user"><%=current_user.email%> <div class="userDrop"></div></div>
    <div class="userDropMenu">
      <div class="userActRow">change password</div>
      <div class="userActRow">sign out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= yield :javascript %>

</body>
</html>
```

With above code the problem is my layout get messed up. Div I updated with partial form shows header so it is layout in a layout but my client_validation_gem properties work. as soon as I say layout false my layout issue get fixed but I lose the client_side_validation gem properties. I dont know what is the issue and I am really frustrated. Any help or direction will be very helpful. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out. I have to remove rails.validations.js file because it was outdated. And add '$('form[data-validate]').validate();' to js file as @David suggested. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not loading the `rails.validations` and `rails.validations.custom` js files if you use `layout: false`. You may have to include them in the partial (something like this).

```
= javascript_include_tag 'rails.validations'
```

**Edit**

Just saw that you're adding the form dynamically. You'll also need to trigger client-side validations like this after adding the form:

```
$('form[data-validate]').validate();
```

Comment: I have added rails.validations in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file. How I can include them in partial?

Comment: See my edit. When you render with `layout: false` the layout file (in your case `application.html`) is skipped, that's why your application.js is not included.

Comment: sorry may be I am not understanding very clear you mean I should add `<%= javascript_include_tag "rails.validations" %>` this in partial if yes then stil I have the same issue.

Comment: no errors. Plus I just check one of the function from rails.validations and it works in console(after i render partial)

Comment: Try `$('form[data-validate]').validate();` in the console and check if the validations work after.

Comment: This is what i get from above command in console `c.validator {settings: Object, currentForm: form#new_policy.new_policy, labelContainer: x.fn.x.init[0], errorContext: x.fn.x.init[1], containers: x.fn.x.init[0]…}'